# How to identify slow queries in PostgreSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, function, performance, query-optimization, plpgsql

How can I identify slow queries in a Postgres function?

For example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function ()
RETURNS void AS $$ 
BEGIN
    query#1;
    
    query#2; --> slow query (duration 4 sec)
    
    query#3;
    
    query#4;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

After executing `my_function()` I get something like this in my Postgres log file:

> duration: 4.904 ms  statement: select my_function ();",,,,,,,,,"psql"

So I can't identify slow queries in my function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, PL/pgSQL functions are black boxes to the Postgres query planner and logging.

The additional module [**`auto_explain`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) allows for more insights. It can be loaded dynamically, but you have to be a **superuser**. (Does not have to be installed like most other modules.)

To load it an individual session:

```sql
LOAD 'auto_explain';
-- SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 1; -- exclude very fast trivial queries?
SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = ON; -- statements inside functions
-- SET auto_explain.log_analyze = ON; -- get actual times, too?
```

Any query running in the same session will get extra logging. Just:

```
SELECT my_function();  -- your function
```

See:

- [Get query plan for SQL statement nested in a PL/pgSQL function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23357/3684)